# Javascript Escaping dynamic html string AND inner string

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am building a web based application that works with js & php. I've got most things up and running however I am having an issue with escaping the onclick & the outter string. I would like to send the arr[i].machine variable into the onclick gotoMachine method/function. I am not familiar with how to escape both. Thanks

```
DynamicHtml += "<tr><td onclick='populateModal()'>" + arr[i].step + "</td><td></td><td>"+ arr[i].task +"</td><td onclick='gotoMachine(* VAR HERE*)'>"+ arr[i].machine +"</td> </tr>"
```

Comment: `onclick='populateModal(" + arr[i].machine + ")'` *if* `arr[i].machine` is a string. Otherwise you cannot use this inline method to do it, you would need to pass something in so you either need a wrapping function. or a reference to it somewhere.

Comment: Is `arr[i].machine` a string or integer value?

Comment: It is a string. Your onclick='populateModal(" + arr[i].machine + ")'  does put the value int there but it says its not defined my guess is because the value needs to have quotes around it like gotoMachine('108')